# uk visa refusal for mrcp paces exam

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image: Refusal Notice Part 1]
[image: Refusal Notice Part 2]

I had applied for uk visa for mrcp paces exam on 23rd june 2016. I am Undergoing Training in cardiology and receiving RS 18000(120 UK POUNDS) per month as stipend. the transaction they have shown is from my mothers account and I can also prove that she supports me financially as I take her monthly house rent.I have evidence of this transaction as well. Kindly suggest a way out.

Comment: Next paragraph of refusal:

Comment: just had my caps on

Comment: i have to appear in paces exam on 23rd june...should i go for a reapplication n if yes what documents i require

Comment: i edited the question by offsetting the caps.....i intended to take a paces course in london on 18 and 19 june but didnt book it nor do i have any evidence as fee is paid there n then....should i tell them about that...thats why i had london in my stay n train of wolverhampton just takes 2 hours from london

Comment: I'm suprised to see "lacs" mentioned in a UK visa refusal letter.
For the record, it may "only be 2 hours" - but you'll save a *lot* of money by getting a hotel in wolves (much cheaper than London) and not paying for a train ticket every day.

Comment: This is a **classic funds parking scenario** and dup'ed as such.  Classic.  Please see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab for the final three paragraphs of your refusal notice.

Comment: in fresh application should i give them this pre exam course plea...

Comment: @YousufDaud, no. They got you on V 4.2 (a) and (c) and examination documents will not fix that type of refusal.

Comment: @Gayot Fow sir can u please kindly explain...i didnt get it

Comment: @YousufDaud, no you didn't get it, did you? There's no chance somebody could read and digest those links in **6 MINUTES**!  So yes, I reckon so.

Comment: V 4.2 (a) (c)....sir wat does that mean for my future applications

Comment: @YousufDaud it means you painted them a picture and they didn't appreciate it; a fresh application at this point will fail. You're not going to get a UK visa at this point in your life. Take the exam in Egypt or someplace like that.

Comment: if i give them compelling evidence of my financial support and other ties to pakistan ...are there any chances

Comment: @YousufDaud, take it chat and see what the people think, chat is here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39899/discussion-between-gayot-fow-and-yousuf-daud).