# UK visa refusal, now applying for Malta Schengen visa to sit MRCP paces exam

Tags: schengen, malta

I have been refused a UK visa once for my Membership of the Royal Colleges of Physicians of the United Kingdom Practical Assessment of Clinical Examination Skills examination. Now I am applying to sit it in Malta, a Schengen state, in December.

What are my chances of securing the Schengen visa in this scenario?

I didn't reapply for a UK visa as per advice of worthy member Gayot Fow.

Comment: Please add your personal details, like nationality, to this question. And if you think it is helpful, also link to the earlier question in this one.

Comment: Original question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68506/uk-visa-refusal-for-mrcp-paces-exam

Comment: Magnetic resonance cholangiopancreatography?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Member of the Royal Colleges of Physicians. Members are entitled to use the letters MRCP after their names. Obtaining membership through examination to one of the colleges is a prerequisite to practising certain kinds of speciality medicine in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

We cannot possibly guess what your chances are since we don't know your particular circumstances or the data about you in UK or Schengen databases. But there are some things which can be said.

- Both the UK and the Schengen area welcome genuine tourists and try to keep illegal immigrants out. If the UK concluded from your application that you **may** become an illegal immigrant, then Schengen might come to the same conclusion unless your circumstances changed in the meantime.
- Malta is a less attractive destination for illegal immigrants than the UK, but it is part of the Schengen area and the Maltese officials will wonder if you are trying to immigrate into *another* Schengen country. Depending on your current circumstances, they **may** be less concerned that you would overstay in Malta than in the UK.
- The UK and Schengen exchange information. The Maltese officials will be aware that your UK application was refused even if you did not mention it yourself.

Summarized, Malta might reject your application for the same reasons as the UK.

Comment: As per questions on this site, and a bit of personal experience, UK Visitor visa is way difficult than Schengen, for exact same financial and other circumstances..

Comment: Wouldn't the OP also state on the application for the Maltese visa that they have been refused a UK visa recently? +1

Comment: Even if Malta is not itself an attractive immigration target, Maltese consular officers are obliged to consider the risk that a prospective traveler would abscond to one of the more attractive Schengen countries instead of returning home. After all, the same visa will let them travel to everywhere in the area, and the treaty framework depends on states watching each others' backs with regard to this.

Comment: +1, remember Malta will check the VIS and be looking to refuse on reason #2 on an incoherent premise (it means... the IO will be all like HUH?, Malta? WTF? What's wrong with a cheaper, more local place?). Also I do hope you will take Henning's comment to heart and put it in your answer; it's a great point.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, edited.

Comment: ok... thanx everyone for their suggestions.

Comment: i have to give 4 options for international paces centers and on top i have selected local centers... its not my prerogrative to choose a center..